# High Memory can't be written in Protected Mode

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I have been following the BrokenThorn OSDev tutorials with Bochs and it worked well (vga-info acquisition, MemoryDump was written by me in real mode and also had some graphics in 320*200*256).
However after entering protected mode(PM) in Demo4 (Kernel loaded at 0x100000 (1Mb)) I noticed that I can't write to high memory (e.g. 0xD0000000)
My MemDump works well because I tested it with 0x7c00 where my bootloader was loaded and the messages of the bootloader were printed with MemDump and I also wrote a few 0x66s to 7c00. The code of the kernel at 0x100000 was also correctly dumped.

This is the code that writes 0x66 from 0xD0000000 (Intel-syntax, Nasm):

```
     mov edi, 0xD0000000        
     mov BYTE [edi], 0x66  (.Next; this is at the beginning of the line)
     inc edi
     cmp edi, 0xD0000010
     jnz .Next
```

I added it to Stage3.asm right after ClrScr32 and MemDump prints from 0xB8000

And the MemDump:

```
    mov esi, 0xD0000000
    mov ecx, 24     ; prints 24 lines (16 bytes per line)
    call MemDump
```

Always FF is shown from 0xD0000000, so I can't write data to high memory.
The GDT is correctly set (I didn't change the one given by BrokenThorn), r/w bit is 1, the segment limit is the maximum with granularity-bit set.

If any of you encountered this problem and/or has a solution, please don't hesitate to share it with me.

Best regards,
rob

(Demo4 can be found at: Tutorial 11, Prepare for the kernel, part 2)
http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevIndex.html

Comment: What OS are you running - is it different than the demo?

Comment: I am running Debian Linux but the OS development is done with Bochs. BrokenThorn uses Windows.

Comment: Is there any memory there to write to? From what I saw in the tutorial, you probably aren't using paging, which means you can only write to that address if you have more than 3.25 GB of RAM in the virtual machine. I believe bochs uses either 32 or 64 MB by default, so you are trying to write to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You must be right. I just tried it with 0x200000. I wote a few bytes to 0x200000 and they were dumped correctly. So this must be Bochs not having that much memory as you said. According to vgainfo, the vga framebuffer is from E0000 (E000:0000 in real mode) and not e.g. F0000000. Probably because of this. Thanks! Sorry for all the fuss.